# Regex returning different result on same input

Tags: c#, regex

I am checking for some results and passing two inputs from a document, two inputs looks same but why are they returning different output.
my regex is

```
(?<preandconjunct>(?:\b([Ss]ubsection|[Ss]ection|[Aa]rticle) +)(?<conjunct>(?:(?<level>(?:(?:[IVXivx]{1,5}(?![A-Z]))|(?:[A-Z]{1,2}(?![A-Z]))|(?:[0-9]+)))|(?<level>\((?:(?:[IVXivx]{1,5}(?![A-Z]))|(?:[A-Z]{1,2}(?![A-Z]))|(?:(?!in|or|if|of|to|as|at|it|no|an)[a-z]{1,2}(?![a-z]))|(?:[0-9]+))\))|(?<level>[\.-](?:(?:[IVXivx]{1,5}(?![A-Z]))|(?:[A-Z]{1,2}(?![A-Z]))|(?:[0-9]+))))+)(?=$|[ ,;.)]))
```

and the two inputs are

> **a dispute under Section 3.1 (which shall be governed exclusively by Section 3.1) or as set forth in Section 11.3(b), the indemnification provisions of this Article XI and Article XII are the sole and exclusive remedies of the Parties pursuant to this Agreement or in connection with the transactions contemplated hereby.  From and after the Closing, to the maximum extent permitted by Law, except with respect to claims based on intentional fraud, a dispute under Section 3.1 (which shall be governed exclusively by Section 3.1),**

and

> **a dispute under Section 3.1 (which shall be governed exclusively by Section 3.1) or as set forth in Section 11.3(b), the indemnification provisions of this Article XI and Article XII are the sole and exclusive remedies of the Parties pursuant to this Agreement or in connection with the transactions contemplated hereby.  From and after the Closing, to the maximum extent permitted by Law, except with respect to claims based on intentional fraud, a dispute under Section 3.1 (which shall be governed exclusively by Section 3.1),**

also i am expecting

*Section 3.1*

*Section 3.1*

*Section 11.3(b)*

*Article XI*

*Article XII*

*Section 3.1*

**Section 3.1**

last one is not showing up in first input.

Comment: Look, [it matches well](https://regex101.com/r/8aQbs1/1) (same results are obtained at http://regexstorm.net/tester).

Comment: So you're basically asking what the difference are between the two texts? The answer is, there aren't any.

Comment: Well if they are returning different outputs for the same regex - they are not the same. Check difference in whitespaces, maybe some invisible characters and so on.

Comment: @Evk Well, that's what I (and Wiktor) are saying - they **are** the same and return the same result.

Comment: yes you guys are right about it. i have decimal charater 160 rather than 32. how can i capture all kind of spaces, like \s is not capturing 160(\u00A0 in hex).

Comment: My *guess* is that the two texts **aren't** the same, because of something that the OP isn't showing us. (The two texts, as displayed here on SO, are indeed identical.) Is there some extra whitespace, or a different character encoding, or a non-printable character, or ...... ?

Comment: ^^^ Yep, so it was a non-printable character. Go figure. I suggest you edit your question, to explain the real problem.

Comment: @TomLord yes there is. please see my last comment. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44409692/edit) to add any details which turn out to be important.

Answer (score 0):

> last one is not showing up in first input

One way of getting all characters is to consume up to an anchor character. For example take the text `blah blah Section 3.1 (governed by Section 3.1)`. We have three anchors, `Section`, `(` and `)`. Let us create a pattern based off of those literal anchors.

I now will comment my regex *pattern* which needs `IgnorePattnerWhiteSpace` to work properly in the regex parser btw.

```
(((Sub)?Section)|Article)\s+    # Anchor of Section or Article or Subsection
(?<Number>[^\s]+)               # Number involved
\s+
   \(                           # Anchor of '('
      (?<Conjuct>[^)]+)         # Consume til next anchor
   \)                           # ')' anchor.
```

By using the **Not** set `[^ ]` we can consume any funky characters which are **not** an ending `)` anchor. Our match result looks like this

[image]

> why are they returning different output.

You need to make the capturing less complex by maybe looking at the literal anchors as mentioned. Maybe even do a two pass regex by first creating general tokens of the text and upon the second regex pass, extract specific items from the tokens?

Also comment your pattern as I have done and work on individual pieces of it, once the individual items are working bring the whole pattern together.